# Finding a basis for a eigenspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, hamel-basis

I have the linear transformation $L_1: V \rightarrow V$ (where $V = \mathbb{C}[x,y]$  is the vector space of polynomials with complex coefficients) defined as:

$L_1(f(x,y)) =  \frac{f(x,y)+f(y,x)}{2}$

I have found the eigenspaces for $L_1$ as $E_0$ = $ker(L_1) = \{f(x,y) \in V:f(x,y)=-f(y,x)\}$ and $E_1 = im(L_1) = \{f(x,y) \in V: f(x,y)=f(y,x)\}$. Now I want to find a basis for these vector spaces. I tried writing out all the elements in each space, for example for $E_0$: $\{x-y, x^2 - y^2, x^3-y^3, ...\}$. I think this is a basis for $E_0$ but I am not sure if this is the best approach.

Thanks!

Comment: The set is not a basis as the vector $xy(x - y) \in E_0$ is not in the span of the set (nor is any other polynomial with mixed terms).

Comment: Ohh, you're right! Is there a more general way of finding a basis? I don't like the approach of just trying to find all polynomials that are included in $E_0$.

Comment: Jose found a basis, but to answer your more general question, there isn't typically an algorithmic way to find a basis in an infinite dimensional vector space. You have to have some special knowledge about the space, or be prepared to deal with a basis you can't explicitly construct. In this case, polynomials of two variables aren't that hard to deal with. I think the issue was that you found an infinite linearly independent set, but didn't check the spanning condition.

Comment: Okay, I see. Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are thinking right, but you are missing the monomials of the type $x^ky^l$, with $k,l\geqslant0$. Actually, a basis of $E_0$ is the set of all polynomials of the type $x^ky^l-x^ly^k$, with $k>l\geqslant0$. And a basis of $E_1$ is the set of all polynomals $x^ky^l+x^ly^k$ with $k\geqslant l\geqslant0$.

Comment: Ahhh thank you that makes sense!!